# Use python code to read accuracy rather than tensorboard

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard

I am using Tensorflow 2.2.

I have written the accuracy for each epoch to the events for reading by tensorboard. By is it possible to get the event file information with python? If yes, is there any code sample for it?

Answer (score 0):

In Keras when you train your model you will have code as shown below. You can get the training accuracy, training loss, validation accuracy and validation loss as  as shown in the code.

```
results = model.fit_generator(generator = generators[0], validation_data= generators[2], 
                               epochs=epochs, initial_epoch=start_epoch,
                               callbacks = callbacks, verbose=1)
acc=results.history['accuracy']
loss=results.history['loss']
vacc =results.history['val_accuracy']
vloss=results.history['val_loss']

each is a list containing the data for each epoch
```